# (Node.js Socket.io) Server and client can't connect

Tags: node.js

Server code

```js
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.on("connection",()=>{
    console.log("Connected");
});

server.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Ready");
});
```

Client Code

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

socket.connect();
```

Execute code and no error.
Just can't connect.

WHY?!

Answer (score 0):

```
        //let's have a simple example 

        //Server 
        var app = require('express')();
        var server = require('http').Server(app);
        var io = require('socket.io')(server);

        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        });

        server.listen(8080);

        //Client

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('/');
        </script>


    //Sending Data from Server to Client


    //Server

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('announcements', { message: 'A new user has joined!' });
    });


    //Client

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('/');
        socket.on('announcements', function(data) {
            console.log('Got announcement:', data.message);
        });
    </script>

//Sending Data from Client to Server

//Server

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('event', function(data) {
        console.log('A client sent us this dumb message:', data.message);
    });
});

//Client

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('/');
    socket.emit('event', { message: 'Hey, I have an important message!' });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want use express, just socket.io without html
Js file <-> Js file Communication